# How to re-use this code?. Want to learn new things in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet below. Can I re-use the `var alertt` or possible how?. I tried to re-use it as below code but not working. I also try to `alertt();` but the console say `Uncaught TypeError: alertt is not a function`.

```js
$("#click").click(function(){
alertt;
})

var alertt = $(function(){
  alert("Message");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="click">
Click me
</button>
```

Hope someone understand it. Want to learn new things.

Comment: `var alertt = function() { alert('msg') };` then `$("#click").click(alertt);`

Comment: @haim770 please try it in fiddle to see your output.

Comment: @Satpal sorry I test it like I comment in Arkadiusz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you're creating `alertt` as a document.ready event handler, not an explicit function. To fix this place the logic within a correctly defined function and then call it on load and when the button is clicked. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#click").click(alertt); // on click
  alertt(); // on load
});

var alertt = function() {
  alert("Message");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="click">Click me</button>
```

Note that you could also just raise a `click()` event on load to avoid having to call the function directly:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#click").click(alertt).click();
});

var alertt = function() {
  alert("Message");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="click">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You need to set the 'Load type' to 'No wrap - in <head>' in the settings of the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2u010eg6/3/

Comment: Thanks its okay now. I change the loadType to onDomReady